# External monitor goes black after a couple of seconds

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, vga, amd-radeon

I have an external monitor connected to my laptop via VGA to adapter to hmdi port. When I first connect them, everything would work fine but then the external monitor would suddenly turn off and won't turn back on until I've unplug and then replug the cables. I have it set up so that the monitor would just be an extension of my laptop. As the monitor turns black, I can move my cursor and programs across the dual screens as if the monitor is still connected making me assume the cable is not the issue.

It was working fine for a couple hours, but then my laptop fell asleep and it hasn't been working properly since then. I've already tried updating my AMD graphics but it hasn't affected anything.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do would be to diagnose the hardware.

For example: Try using the monitor with another computer, try a different cable, try using a device that does not require the adapter, try another monitor with the laptop (such as a TV, etc.).

There are so many possibilities of error, we cannot guess what the solution would be. Your best bet is to test each piece of hardware and see if the problem occurs in another scenario. The issue can be either the monitor, cable, adapter, laptop port, or the video card/GPU on the laptop.

I can tell that if you can still move your mouse to the other screen when it is black, than the laptop knows that there is a connection between your computer and the monitor.